# What does it essentially mean if the neural network has convex error surface?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, machine-learning, linear-regression, neural-networks

Suppose if I am building a Linear Regression model with one fully connected layer and a sigmoid with minimizing mean squared error as objective. I understand that this network has a convex error surface since the functions involved, affine transformation, sigmoid, and objective are convex.

$$y' = sigmoid(W.X + b)$$
Minimize $$ (y - y')^2 $$
where $X$ is input vector,
 $y$ is the actual output,
 $y'$ is the predicted output and,
 $W$ is the parameter matrix.

Since it is a convex surface, we will be able to find a global optimum. However, if the data is not linearly separable, is the global optimum we found is still the best solution? Is it possible to have a better solution with the addition of extra layers and convex or non-convex non-linearity?

Comment: This question very much reads lie a "do my homework" post.  You are more likely to get useful answers if you edit your question to "[Provide details.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) Share your research."